# Best way to parse hexadecimal string into binary char

Tags: c++, hex

I have a big hexidemical (in a std::string representation) that I need to parse into an binary representation (probably unsigned char*) to use with OpenSSL's sha256 function, in order to create a hash. In binary representation I do not mean a binary string, however actual binary data. I am struggling a little bit to find a good solution to do this conversion, and hoped that someone could help.

One example of this in C style is provided here in the hex2bin function (link due to copyright notice) http://pastebin.com/bW3fQA2a

**Edit:**

To clarify, yes the hex string will be longer than longs (and long longs).

Comment: changed the question to reflect that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
void readStr(const std::string& str, unsigned char* output) {
   for (size_t s = 0; s < str.size() ; s+= 2){
        std::string twoChars = str.substr(s,2); // Read two chars
        unsigned char c = (unsigned char)std::stoi( twoChars,0,16); // Transform them to a 1-byte int
        *output = c; // Write byte into buffer and advance
        c++;
   }
}
```

This allows transforming arbitrary length strings into byte arrays. It works by simply picking two hex digits at a time (one byte), converting it using `stoi` and writing it into the output buffer.